# Badge requirements on beta sites

Tags: discussion, badges, area-51, beta-phase

I know that the reputation requirements for various privileges are kept lower on [SE's beta sites](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta).

My suggestion is, shouldn't the threshold for acquiring badges be lowered too for such sites? I'd quote here what SE refers to as a [beta](/questions/tagged/beta) phase of a website.

> This is the actual, live site set up on a "**probationary**" basis to see
>   if people use it. It is very important to participate early. The
>   earliest questions set the tone and topic of the site for a long time.
>   This is also the time to spread the word via Twitter, blogs, and email
>   far and wide.

So, while we can reduce the threshold for badges such as **Excavator** or **Deputy** badge, we can; on the other hand; increase the number of visits for *Announcer* badge.

What are the views of other members about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason to lower the threshold for privileges is to get the site up and running fast (having some users with edit/close privileges greatly enhances the site and lightens the moderator load).

Badges have mostly brag value, this is not needed to operate the site so there is no need to lower this threshold.