# Should a young site recommend me the Excavator badge?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, profile-page

After I had earned the Custodian badge in Portuguese Language SE, I let the system decide the next badge to supposedly aim for, which was then the Excavator badge. The problem is that Portuguese.SE has only been in private beta for [nearly 2 days](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64172/portuguese-language), and so this badge cannot be attained until posts can be 6 months old. There were even other better candidates for next badge that an active user could obtain much sooner.

[image: next badge]

I do understand this is a minor issue and does not affect the overall quality of the site in any way, but given the fact that not all badges can be achieved at the time of recommendation, what if the recommendation system would keep that in mind in the first place? Is it too troublesome to implement?

Comment: This is actually kinda funny, and worth fixing!

Comment: I think this has been brought up before, but I suppose it's still out there.

Comment: Couldn't find a duplicate in my search, but I don't doubt that.

Comment: Related: [Badge requirements on beta sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172960/badge-requirements-on-beta-sites)

Comment: Was supposed to have been fixed along with all the other months-long badges: [Where is the Archaeologist badge?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292206/where-is-the-archaeologist-badge/292393#292393)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can blame caching here.

For some reason, the private beta start date was missing - this was cached, causing our badges test to use a default date (defaulting to 6 months ago).

Therefore, suggesting these inappropriate badges.

I have cleared this cache and all is well in the world.

Answer (score 7):

Seems this was reported and [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) in the new profile page bug list:

[New profile pages are out - bugs and feedback master list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list/253497#253497)

Looks like it needs to be revisited?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose so even though it isn't that important since you could manually change it yourself anyways...

There could be a change in the code so that the badge selector could recognize how long the site has been launched into beta. If it is less than 30 days, don't let the system choose "Excavator" or "Necromancer" because you can't earn it yet. If less than 60 days but more than 30 days, don't allow the system to choose "Necromancer" but allow "Excavator". This should also apply to "Archeologist" too and any other badge that deals with time.